# Mysql table truncates by its self in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have MYSQL database in a Laravel project.
The database has several tables which I have many transactions working fine.
Only one table, every now and then it happens to see this table without any data. as if it was truncated. I have no truncate query applied. I don't know how to find the source of the problem. the website hosted on Cpanel. any advice?

Answer (score 0):

**Simple table truncate queries in Laravel:**
The query builder may also be used to delete records from the table via the delete method. You may constrain delete statements by adding where clauses before calling the delete method:

```
Model::truncate();
Model::delete();
```

Without Model:

```
DB::table('table_name')->truncate();
DB::table('table_name')->delete();
```